# SQLite query issue in production app

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I am working with a production app, where a mistake has been made in an SQLite query.

Basically the query should be:

```
 "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id =..."
```

However the actual query that went into production is

```
  "SELECT * FROM people WHERE AND id =..."
```

Is there a way to add a user defined statement to 'ignore' the accidental 'AND' in this query? Or is there another method of doing this?

I can make remote updates to databases, by executing SQL but that is about it.  I can also get users to replace the database file by downloading a new one, so I can make an update at this side and distribute if need be.

Comment: Better think of update your app for a long solution. Hope someone else can suggest you some trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in a database file can modify queries executed by your application.

You have to replace the application.

Comment: I thought this may be the answer. Thanks anyway!